# Can we only recompile a kernel module in kernel source tree?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, rhel

Let's say we install a kernel 2.6.32.el6, then we download the 2.6.32.el6.src.rpm, can we just install the source and modify some module, and use make -C 2.6.32.el6.src.source.directry -M$PWD in the module directory to compile the module, then we copy into /lib/modules/2.6.32.el6/kernel/moduledirectory and the new module would work?

I try to modify kvm modules and compile it, but when I recompile the module and copy it into the directory, machine said when booting:

kvm: no symbol version for module_layout
kvm_intel: no symbol version for module_layout

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably linux kernel 2.6.32.el6 has been compiled with modversions but your module was compiled without it. Check if you have CONFIG_MODVERSIONS selected or deselected in your kernel config file. Compare it with /proc/.config file which is the kernel confguration file - of course if you have it.

In other words - probably your linux kernel requires that modules supports versioning, but your module doesn't provide it.